# Conversion PDF to XML renders whitespaces weirdly

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, xml, pdf

I have a PDF document that has to be converted into XML. I tried with a very similar one and it all went well. However, this time not only some words are not in the right place, but also the whitespace structure in the text tag is like this:

```
<text bbox="353.688,553.628,359.484,566.110" colourspace="DeviceN" ncolour="[1]" size="12.482">o</text>
<text bbox="359.373,553.628,363.200,566.110" colourspace="DeviceN" ncolour="[1]" size="12.482">]</text>
<text> </text>
<text bbox="366.782,553.639,372.578,566.366" colourspace="DeviceN" ncolour="[1]" size="12.727">p</text>
<text bbox="372.467,553.639,376.984,566.366" colourspace="DeviceN" ncolour="[1]" size="12.727">r</text>
```

There are weird empty text tags, while with the other file I tried the whitespace is inside the text tag with attributes. I need help on how to preserve whitespace without that weird tag. I tried changing LAparams a bit, nothing helped though.

The code:

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import HTMLConverter,TextConverter,XMLConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
import io

def convert(case, pdfpath, targetfilepath, pages=100):
    if not pages: pagenums = set();
    else:         pagenums = set(pages);
    manager = PDFResourceManager()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    caching = True


    if case == 'text':
        output = io.StringIO()
        converter = TextConverter(manager, output, codec=codec, laparams=LAParams())
    if case == 'HTML':
        output = io.BytesIO()
        converter = HTMLConverter(manager, output, codec=codec, laparams=LAParams())
    if case == 'XML':
        output = io.BytesIO()
        converter = XMLConverter(manager, output, codec=codec, laparams= LAParams())

    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(manager, converter)
    infile = open(pdfpath, 'rb')

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(infile, pagenums,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

    convertedPDF = output.getvalue()

    infile.close(); converter.close(); output.close()

    convertedFile = open(targetfilepath, 'wb')
    convertedFile.write(convertedPDF)
    convertedFile.close()

print(convert('XML', 'sposipromessi3.pdf', 'sposipromessi3.xml', pages=None))
```

The output I want is:

```
<text bbox="353.688,553.628,359.484,566.110" colourspace="DeviceN" ncolour="[1]" size="12.482">o</text>
<text bbox="359.373,553.628,363.200,566.110" colourspace="DeviceN" ncolour="[1]" size="12.482">]</text>
<text bbox="359.373,553.628,363.200,566.110" colourspace="DeviceN" ncolour="[1]" size="12.482"> </text>
<text bbox="366.782,553.639,372.578,566.366" colourspace="DeviceN" ncolour="[1]" size="12.727">p</text>
<text bbox="372.467,553.639,376.984,566.366" colourspace="DeviceN" ncolour="[1]" size="12.727">r</text>
```

I also noticed some words are in the wrong order.

Comment: Nobody answered

Comment: I'll delete last one

Comment: If you want to draw attention to a question, you can start a bounty: https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Comment: Please share the PDF for analysis. Probably no actual space glyph is *drawn* there but the text insertion point merely is moved right, and PdfMiner wanted to indicate that there is a space-like gap (thus, a `text` tag with a space as content) while no glyph is drawn (thus, no drawing-related attributes).

Comment: Here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y0n7fWMX7jP_HaVgZMgk8S9gufZCXaoC/view?usp=sharing is the pdf. I also noticed it doesn't print out the whole text sequentially, while in the attempt of another very similar PDF it did.